# CSS Keyframe animation delay

Tags: html, css

Hello for some reason I cannot seem to get the color squares in the table to appear at different times. I would like it so the first color appears and then disappears, then the second color appears and disappears, then the third color appears then disappears and so on. I would like it so it is in a light sequence.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<center><h1>Light Sequence</h1></center>
<table>
<table style="background-color: #5D5D5D;" table align="center"
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="d"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="a"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="c"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td class="b"></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td class="e"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>

</html>

CSS:
td { width:400px; height:200px; border:2px solid #333; }
td.a { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.b { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.c { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.d { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
td.e { background-color:#5D5D5D; }
.a {
height:200px;
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #333;
-webkit-animation: animate_bg 3s;
animation: animate_bg 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.b {
height:200px;
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #333;
-webkit-animation: animate_bg2 3s;
animation: animate_bg2 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.c {
height:200px;
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #333;
-webkit-animation: animate_bg3 3s;
animation: animate_bg3 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.d {
height:200px;
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #333;
-webkit-animation: animate_bg4 3s;
animation: animate_bg4 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.e {
height:200px;
width: 400px;
border: 2px solid #333;
-webkit-animation: animate_bg5 3s;
animation: animate_bg5 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes animate_bg {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50%   {background-color:yellow;}  
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@keyframes animate_bg {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:yellow;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:yellow;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@keyframes animate_bg2 {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
50% {background-color:green;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}    
}

@keyframes animate_bg2 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:green;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg2 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:green;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}
@keyframes animate_bg3 {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
50% {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}    
}

@keyframes animate_bg3 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg3 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}
@keyframes animate_bg4 {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
50% {background-color:white;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}    
}

@keyframes animate_bg4 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:white;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg4 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:white;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}
@keyframes animate_bg5 {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50%   {background-color:orange;}  
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@keyframes animate_bg5 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:orange;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg5 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:orange;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}
```

Comment: don't think css has a success callback, you might have to use javascript for this.You would be able to set delays in css but unless you got it millisecond perfect it look a bit out n different browsers

Comment: Oh right, do you know how to go about adding a delay in css?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

Comment: CBroe, I see that earlier and tried to add it into my css but unfortunately it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Try to use [animation delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay):

```
div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

Comment: how's this upvoted ? this work does it ? one line of code with HTML and CSS mixed all in one...

Comment: Yes the up vote did work, I have managed to get the timing but cannot seem to repeat the animation, it only plays once in the correct timing and then after it goes funny.

Answer (score 0):

here's it running, explanation in the html..

```css
table{text-align:center;background-color:#5d5d5d;}
td { width:400px; height:100px; border:2px solid #333;  background-color:#5D5D5D; }

.a {
-webkit-animation: animate_bg 3s;
animation: animate_bg 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.b {
 
-webkit-animation: animate_bg2 3s;
animation: animate_bg2 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.c {


-webkit-animation: animate_bg3 3s;
animation: animate_bg3 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation-delay: 4s;
}
.d {
 
-webkit-animation: animate_bg4 3s;
animation: animate_bg4 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.e {

-webkit-animation: animate_bg5 3s;
animation: animate_bg5 3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
   -webkit-animation-delay: 8s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-delay: 8s;
  
}

@keyframes animate_bg {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50%   {background-color:yellow;}  
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@keyframes animate_bg {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:yellow;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:yellow;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@keyframes animate_bg2 {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
50% {background-color:green;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}    
}

@keyframes animate_bg2 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:green;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg2 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:green;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}
@keyframes animate_bg3 {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
50% {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}    
}

@keyframes animate_bg3 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg3 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:blue;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}
@keyframes animate_bg4 {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
50% {background-color:white;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}    
}

@keyframes animate_bg4 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:white;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg4 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:white;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}
@keyframes animate_bg5 {  
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50%   {background-color:orange;}  
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@keyframes animate_bg5 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:orange;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate_bg5 {
0%   {background-color:#5D5D5D;}
50% {background-color:orange;}
100% {background-color:#5D5D5D;}  
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Light Sequence with css only</h1>
  <p>Put the color,width and height of td's in the top declaration only as they were needlessly repeated multiple times. I didn't realise myself, but for animation delay to work it has to be after the animation call, seems to work then. Mucked around with the timing but couldn't get them to stay in time.2 table tags, one with style removed and style put in css.
    </p>


</section>
<table>
<tr>
  
    <td class="a">a</td>
    <td class="b">b</td>
    <td class="c">c</td>
    <td class="d">d</td>
    <td class="e">e</td>
   
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but unfortunately this did not work, thanks anyway.

Comment: back now, i was rushing out the door, I'll have a better look now, give me 15 and i'll update the answer

Comment: Ok, I have managed to get everything working but I cannot seem to make the CSS animation continue to play?

Answer (score 0):

Create youy own animation:

```
div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
-webkit-animation: myfirst 5s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation: myfirst 5s;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background: red;}
    20%   {background: red;}
    25%  {background: yellow;}
    40%  {background: yellow;}
    50%  {background: blue;}
    70%  {background: blue;}
    75% {background: green;}
    95% {background: green;}
    100% {background: red;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background: red;}
    20%   {background: red;}
    25%  {background: yellow;}
    40%  {background: yellow;}
    50%  {background: blue;}
    70%  {background: blue;}
    75% {background: green;}
    95% {background: green;}
    100% {background: red;}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DariuszMusielak/L9fmktvr/